# property can be apply to all label if one of the label property change in wpf and vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tags, label

i have three label and i given them tag value 0 to 2 if any user dynamically change property of the one of label then that change reflate in all control i have dynamic property window at where user can change the style.

how i can apply changes??

my label property at design side is following:

```
 <Label Content="Kaju Kari" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  Margin="498.821,180,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Tag="0"/>
  <Label Content="Paneer Kadai" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="493.821,213,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Tag="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your labels to the properties changing in your ViewModel.

Note that your ViewModel needs to implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Besides that, the affected properties will also need to publish notifications to the View in order to signal, that they have changed and therefore need an update in the View.

That being said, you will need to have 2 properties, bound to your 2 labels in order to archive the reflection. You just need to change the second property within the `setter` method of your first property.

That might look as follows:

```
private string _Property1;
private string _Property2;

public string Property1
{
    set 
    { 
        if(_Property1) == value) return;
        _Property1 = value;
        _Property2 = value;
        OnPropertyChange(() => Property1);
    }
 }
```